# In what situation can we Non-shareable device memory, or Shareable device memory?

Tags: memory, arm

In ARM, memory types are specified as :

1. Normal
2. Device
3. Strongly-Ordered

within Device type, it seems this type also could be distinguished

1. Non-shareable Device Memory
2. Shareable Device Memory

what is the difference between Non-shareable, shareable Device memory?
and how can we use these memory respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shareable attribute means different things when it is applied to Normal or Device memory and with ARMv7 there is no such thing as non-shareable Device memory.

Below is from [Cortex A Series Programmers Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013d/index.html):

For memory designated as Device:

> ... Shareable attribute of Device accesses is used to determine
>   which memory interface will be used for the access, with memory
>   accesses to areas marked as Device, Non-Shareable performed using a
>   dedicated interface, the private peripheral port. This mechanism is
>   not used on ARMv7 processors.

For memory designated as Normal:

> Normal memory must also be designated either as Shareable
>   or Non-Shareable. A region of Normal memory with the Non-Shareable
>   attribute is one that is used only by this core. There is no
>   requirement for the core to make accesses to this location coherent
>   with other cores. If other cores do share this memory, any coherency
>   issues must be handled in software.

For memory designated as Strongly-ordered:

> All memory accesses to Strongly-ordered memory occur in program order.
>   All Strongly-ordered accesses are assumed to be shared.

Comment: @user3444572 This is not a comment, this is an answer and a good one. You should accept it rather than "appreciate". I understand it was a while ago, but it is not late now.

Answer (score 1):

```
ARM Architecture Reference Manual (ARM DDI 0100I) 
Table B2-2 Memory attribute summary
Device Shared     Designed to handle memory mapped peripherals
                  that are shared by several processors.
       Non-Shared Designed to handle memory mapped peripherals
                  that are used only by a single processor.
```